# Application background for iOS application on both iPhone4(s) and 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to make a GUI for my first Objective-C application. However, I am kind of stuck at the background.

I need to apply a background which'll work on both iPhone4(s) and 5. How do you do that? I guess resolutions aren't the same on the devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a couple different ways of doing this. One is to create separate storyboards/xibs for each screen size. Another is to use the condition:

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].height == 568) {
    //
}
```

Or, if your background is a pattern image you only need to apply it once and it will work on both screen sizes, it's as easy as:

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create the background image for the size of the iPhone 5 and set the frame for the size of the iPhone 5 as well.

When the app is opened on the iPhone 4 it will truncate the bottom piece of the background-- it won't skew it.

If you are using Storyboards, there is a very useful button in the bottom right corner when the storyboard is open (next to the zoom buttons):
[image]

Toggling this will expand/contract your ViewControllers so you can see how it will look for both 3.5 inch (iPhone 4-4s) and 4 inch (iPhone 5) displays.